# Enable inline patterns in python markdown

Tags: python, django, markdown

I'm trying to make my own markdown extension to markdown in django. I'm calling it like

```
markdown.markdown(markup, [neboard_extension])
```

In my extension's extendMarkdown method I see some default patterns (like autolink for example) and add mine. But neither the default autolink nor my patterns work. How can I enable the patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Patterns are order-dependent.

If your pattern interacts with existing patterns, for example:

- by expecting a pattern that is escaped by the EscapePattern before it gets to your extension, then it may hide the pattern that you are looking for.
- by changing the output to something that another Pattern or component modifies, then your output will not look as expected.

One tip is to check the ordering. You can sometimes get around the problem by inserting your extension ahead of all other patterns (for the first scenario above), or after they have all been processed (the second scenario).

There is little discussion about how to protect against this based in the documentation. My experience, after trying to heavily customise python-markdown, is that this is error prone and awkward, with little in the way for introspection for finding out what other patterns are enabled... other than reading the code.